# Mysql find 10 nearest point from given lat/long per type?

Tags: mysql, nearest-neighbor

I have a database given with 3 different types of locations A, B and C. These points have latitude and longitude information with them.

Now I have a random lat-long given and I want to find the closest 10 points **per type** to that given location - how can I do that? Anyone has an idea?`

Thanks for any help

Answer (score -1):

Searching for the nearest 10 points of interest gives, usually, near points. In that case the usual cartesian distance (`SQRT((LAT1 - LAT2)^2 + (LONG1 - LONG2)^2)`) can be used.

Given a generic table (for the definition of latitude and longitude I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504208/what-mysql-data-type-should-be-used-for-latitude-longitude-with-8-decimal-places) pointer.)

```
CREATE TABLE POI (
   ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
 , `Name` Varchar(100)
 , `Type` CHAR(1)
 , `LAT`  Decimal(10, 8)
 , `LNG`  Decimal(11, 8)
)
```

The query would be something like

```
DECLARE myLAT Decimal(10, 8) DEFAULT 45.48561;
DECLARE myLNG Decimal(11, 8) DEFAULT 123.47981;

(SELECT `Name`, `LAT`, `LNG`
 FROM   POI
 WHERE  `Type` = 'A'
 ORDER BY SQRT(POWER(myLAT - `LAT`), 2) + POWER(myLNG - `LNG`), 2)
 LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT `Name`, `LAT`, `LNG`
 FROM   POI
 WHERE  `Type` = 'B'
 ORDER BY SQRT(POWER(myLAT - `LAT`), 2) + POWER(myLNG - `LNG`), 2)
 LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT `Name`, `LAT`, `LNG`
 FROM   POI
 WHERE  `Type` = 'C'
 ORDER BY SQRT(POWER(myLAT - `LAT`), 2) + POWER(myLNG - `LNG`), 2)
 LIMIT 10)
```

In case the point of interest are few and far from the 'here' point and from themselves you have to use a different formula for the distance, to account that the earth is, more or less, a sphere.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the whole table must be scanned and the distance must be calculated for every point. 
Maybe one can use the [spatial extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html)  or one tries to implement some [computational geometry algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_geometry)  without usage of the spatial extension.
Besides the performance problem of your approach it can be severly limited by the fact that the earth is approximately a sphere. But this depends on the data and can be overcome by the appropriate formulas.

Comment: @miracle173 I opened with the hypothesys that **the locations are near the current point** in that case the cartesian distance is a good approximation, you can also see that under the query I pointed out that with few and sparse location the formula need to be changed to account the earth curvature. With that and a good indexing (3 index: `Type`, `LAT` and `LNG`) the component can be limited to one degree in both latitude and longitude adding those condition to the `WHERE` to use an index seek instead of a table scan.

Comment: @Serpiton: This metric is only valid at the equator, as Lat/Long **are not a Euclidean metric** anywhere on the globe. You must first scale the Longitude by sin(Latitude) and then employ Pythagoras to obtain a Euclidean metric.

Comment: @Serpiton: Remember that lines of Longitude converge at the poles. at 45 degrees North or South they are only aout 71% as far apart as at the equator.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Have you fully read my answer? I opened with the assumption that the points of interest are near, say the same city/county, that is the max distance between "here" and the points is less then 100 Km, in that condition an euclidean distance can approximate the spherical distance. I also ended saying that for distant points a different formula is needed.

Comment: Twice through again, and I reiterate: Your formula is flat wrong everywhere except at (or very close to) the equator. You absolutely must multiply longitude values by sin(Latitude) in order to obtain a valid Euclidean approximation, regardless of how close the origin and selected points are to each other. Then employ Pythagoras.